# Convert negation text to text in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-science

I have a lot of data which contain the word "not".

> For example : "not good".

I want to convert **"not good"** to **"notgood"** *(without a space)*.

How can I convert all of the ***"not"s*** in the data, erasing the space after **"not"**.

For example in the below list:

- **1.** I am **not beautiful**  → I am **notbeautiful**
- **2.** She is **not good** to be a teacher → She is **notgood** to be a teacher
- **3.** If I choose A, I think it's **not bad** decision → If I choose A, I think it's **notbad** decision

Answer (score 2):

A simple way to do this would be to replace `not_` with `not`, removing the space.

```
text = "I am not beautiful"
new_text = text.replace("not ", "not")
print(new_text)
```

Will output:

```
I am notbeautiful
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you use regular expression to match the word with boundary, in order to avoid matching phrases like "tying the knot with someone":

```
import re
output = re.replace(r'(?<=\bnot)\s+(?=\w+)', '', text)
```

Answer (score 0):

OR:

```
s = "I am not beautiful"
news=''.join(i+' ' if i != 'not' else i for i in s.split())
print(news)
```

Output:

```
I am notbeautiful
```

If you care about the space at the end do:

```
print(news.rstrip())
```